# how to add jupyterlab to path after installing it in ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, path, jupyter-lab

i am new to ubuntu. i have installed jupyterlab using pip3 but not able to add it to the path. i tried searching on google and using those commands but no use.i tried using the command modifying ~/.profile from root and as sudo too .In windows we use environment variables to change the path but how to do that in ubuntu. is there any similar way?

Answer (score 0):

If it's under your home (~) you should not use sudo, permissions should be set to the user.
Under Unix systems, you use the following syntax to add something to your path:

~/.profile:

```sh
export PATH="/some/path:$PATH"
```

This will **prepend** your current path value, this means that if you have 2 similar binary presents in your PATHs the one declared earlier will take precedence. You can obviously do it the other way and append instead.

Now for your specific case, assuming you are using your system python, you should use:

```sh
pip install --user jupyterlab
```

and then add the following to your ~/.profile:

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then open a new terminal window so that the new profile gets loaded.

All those are very well explained in the official docs tbh: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

In short, run

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

reference: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html